# div doesn't update on Calling watchLocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

Below is the HTML5 code for finding updated geolocation. Latitude and Longitude values pops in alert box. But, the value cannot be assigned to the div using                 **$(id).html(value);** . I am using watchPosition() function.

```
   <html>
     <head>   
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var watchID;
         var geoLoc;

         function showLocation(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude);
             $("#lat").html(latitude);
             $("#long").html(longitude);
             }         

         function errorHandler(err) {
            if(err.code == 1) {
               alert("Error: Access is denied!");
            }

            else if( err.code == 2) {
               alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
            }
         }

         function getLocationUpdate(){
            if(navigator.geolocation){
               // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
               var options = {timeout:60000};
               geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
               watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
            }

            else{
               alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
            }
         }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body>

      <form>
         <input type="button" onclick="getLocationUpdate();" value="Watch Update"/>
         Latitude : <div id="lat"></div>
         Longitude : <div id="long"></div>
       </form>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use alert() it stops all further execution of your code, so move the alert() below your lines assigning the value to the div and that should solve your problem.

```
$("#lat").html(latitude);
$("#long").html(longitude);
alert("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude);
```

Comment: No, it is not working. I removed the alert function and tried too !!

Comment: Actually, where are you including jQuery as you are using the jQuery selector to update the HTML but I can't see and reference to you calling the jQuery script before your script, or that you are initialising jQuery before trying to use it?

Comment: Thanks ... I missed the reference